# Inserting an entity through Entity Framework to a table having default value column

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

A simple situation, but can't think of a simple solution.
I have a table in my MSSQL DB (simplified):
**tbUsers**

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL default GETDATE()
```

And I have an Entity Framework Model generated from database, that created a User POCO class for me.
What I want to achieve is that when using my database context like this

```
db.Users.Add(new User { Name = "Rony" });  
db.SaveChanges();
```

It will create a row having *DateCreated* set to current's date & time. What happens now is that when the `User` object created, the `DateCreated` property defaults to `DateTime.MinValue` and then the row in the db have this value as well.

I guess that the query executed is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbUsers
       ([Name]
       ,[DateCreated])
VALUES
       (''
       ,'0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')
```

But should be:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbUsers
       ([Name])
VALUES
       ('')
```

Any help on achieving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is responsible for setting the field, annotate the property as `Computed`, e.g.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

This can also be set on the property of this field in the EF Designer.

Comment: Thanks. It's the direction I'm looking for, but sadly it doesn't solve the situation when I want to update a record and set DateCreated to something else. I understand that DateCreated in this example is not supposed to be updated, but for example let's think about an "IsVerified" column that on creation defaults to false but in the future may be changed to true when the user is verified by email.